# How to create a tag using TagSupport?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

When I try to extend TagSupport - no class is found.
[image]

The only place were it is located is javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport, but when I add the dependency - here is the exception I have.
[image]

What am I doing wrong to create custom a tag library tag?

Comment: Not sure but try using some lower version.

Comment: @KetanSuthar it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try lowering the version in the pom.xml file (maven file)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1</version> //Like this one!
    </dependency>
```